# mouseenter and mouseover for over animation in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm stuck on a jquery property. I want make an over effect with property mouse enter and mouse leave but i have several images and i would like to do it only on 1 when the mouse enters on this one.

I tried to put several class name but nothing does the hover effect this puts on all the images and not only on the active one.

```html
<div id="villas">
                <div class="l_villa">
                    <a href="./img/villa1.png" alt="villa1">
                        <img id="lv1" src="./img/villa1.png" alt="villa1">
                    </a>
                    <div class="lvinfos1">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="l_villa">
                    <a href="./img/villa2.png" alt="villa2">
                        <img class="lv1" src="./img/villa2.png" alt="villa2">
                    </a>
                    <div class="lvinfos2">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                    </div>
                </div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".l_villa").mouseover(function(){
        $(".lvinfos1").slideUp("slow");

    });
    $(".l_villa").mouseleave(function(){
        $(".lvinfos1").slideDown('slow');

    });
});
```

Comment: Try `$(".lvinfos1", this).slideUp`

Comment: It's the same, but slightly different syntax as the provided answer: `$(this).find(".lvinfos1")` - you should accept that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you require change all the `.lvinfosN` elements to have the same class. I would suggest `.lvinfos`. Then in the event handler use the `this` keyword to refer to the element that raised the event, and use DOM traversal to target the related element to slide up or down. In this case `find()` will work.

Note that the code can be shortened by using the `hover()` method along with `slideToggle()`. In addition it's worth calling `stop()` as well to prevent multiple animations being queued when the user repeatedly mouses in/out of the element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.l_villa').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.lvinfos').stop(true).slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="villas">
  <div class="l_villa">
    <a href="./img/villa1.png" alt="villa1">
      <img id="lv1" src="./img/villa1.png" alt="villa1">
    </a>
    <div class="lvinfos">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="l_villa">
    <a href="./img/villa2.png" alt="villa2">
      <img class="lv1" src="./img/villa2.png" alt="villa2">
    </a>
    <div class="lvinfos">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks you, i have add stop() and yeah it s much better.